# How do I see a list of all suspended users?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, users, account-suspension

Can users be filtered by their "suspended" status? I'd like to see a list of all users who are currently suspended.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No - by design, suspension is a "quiet" business, rather than something advertised widely. The idea is to avoid attracting too much attention to it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NKVD

Comment: Isn't reducing someone's rep to 1, especially if the user is well known to have rep in the 1000s, "attracting too much attention to it"?

Comment: @user1271772: No, I don't think so. There's a difference between doing something that folks would have to spot, and actively advertising it.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I acknowledge that there's a difference between doing something that folks would have to spot, and actively advertising it: but if a user like JonSkeet were to suddenly have their reputation reduced to 1 for a year, that's going to quite obvious. It's not an active advertisement, but it could be humiliating to the user. You said "the idea is to avoid attracting too much attention to it", and reducing the rep to 1 on every single post they've ever written (except on MathOverflow where rep is no longer shown) is not "avoiding" attracting attention to it, nor is it "quiet".

Answer (score 12):

The penalty box isn't the *stocks* or *pillory* used for the scorn of the local peoples, who then take to to insulting, kicking, spitting and in some cases urinating and defecating on its victims.

It's more like the County Lockup where you tuck people away for a day or two so they can cool off or sober up. You can't wander in there an say, "**So let's see who you have here this weekend.**"